# Using Python, how to find XOR of two strings having hexadecimal values

Tags: python, hex, xor

s1 = '0x54'

s2 = '0xa1'

How do we XOR s1 and s2 to get '0xf5' as output?

Comment: `0x54 ^ 0xa1` ??

Comment: No they are hex values but their type is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1 = '0x54'
s2 = '0xa1'

def XOR(s1, s2):
   return "0x" + "{:x}".format(int(s1[2:], 16)^int(s2[2:], 16))

XOR(s1,s2)
```

That should work

Answer (score 3):

First convert them to numeric values:

```
n1 = int(s1, 0)
n2 = int(s2, 0)
```

Now compute the `XOR` of the values using the `^` operator, and convert to `hex` format:

`result = hex(n1 ^ n2)`

Answer (score 0):

RUN:

```
print(hex(int(s1,16)^int(s2,16)))
```